# Segfault on some steam_api.dll calls from executable compiled with MinGW GCC. Any way to determine which DLL is loaded?

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64, msys2, steamworks-api

I am making a C++ game and integrating Steam's API on Windows MinGW GCC via MSYS2 environment. I am successfully linking to the library, and some of the functions run properly.

I am able to initialize steamworks and run SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName(), and it returns my own steam user as expected.

However, when I run SteamUser()->GetSteamID() it gives me a segfault. Upon debugging, I have found that SteamUser() returns an address (it is not NULL), but the address does not address a valid ISteamUser class/struct. I am beginning to believe that perhaps the DLL that windows loads for steam_api is not the one which I linked for.

Is there any way to determine this? Also does anyone have any other debug methodologies they would use to try to identify the problem?

I have also compiled an identical application using visual studio and it does not experience the segfault, so I have isolated the issue to something external to my code for certain, probably relating to the way the DLL is linked.

Comment: Dependency Walker should tell you which dll it loads. There's also ntldd.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Does Dependency Walker have a way to see which actual dll file is loaded? I'm concerned it is loading another version of the library from a system dir instead of the version I compiled with.

Comment: I've not used it for a while, but I think so? Try it.

Comment: The directory with the .exe has the most priority. If the .dll is sitting next to the .exe, it's going to get used.

Comment: I found it the dll location. This is a big help thank you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat curiously, it seems that it is not loading a local DLL. https://i.imgur.com/R78OjDA.png -- I have put this STEAMCLIENT64.DLL that is named in the error in the local directory and it is prioritizing the system dir one.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the bitness is different (x32 vs x64)?

Comment: That's the line of thinking I was going down as well. I will investigate. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It turns out the LoadLibraryExW calls Steam does are with the LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH property, so they override the default search paths. example: LoadLibraryExW("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamclient64.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) called from "c:\msys64\home\...\steamworks-cli\STEAM_API64.DLL" at address 0x00007FFF457C655A by thread 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SteamUser()->GetSteamID()` crash is due to the C++ ABI differences between MINGW (used by your app) and MSVC (used by Steam DLLs). Basically `GetSteamID()` returns not just integer value, but `CSteamID` class, and the binary conventions for passing a class value are different in different compilers.

Related SteamWorks discussions (accessible only for approved Steam developers):

- https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/0/358416640405914974/
- https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/0/282992646967220526/

To fix this call (and possibly other SteamAPI calls with the same problem), you can use C API from `<steam/steam_api_flat.h>`, which does not suffer from ABI differences:

```cpp
SteamAPI_ISteamUser_GetSteamID(SteamUser())
```

It is OK to mix usage of C and C++ API, so you can still use C++ API most of the time, and use C API only for problematic calls.

Or you can switch to MSVC or MSVC-clang.